# Raspberry OS Bullseye Camera Module - No cameras available

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, libcamera

I did a clean install of Raspberry OS Bullseye 32bits in a RPi 4 8gb kernel 5.10.78-v7l+, and I just installed a camera module rev v1.3 (P5V04A SUNNY) and I'm trying to test it with the command:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ libcamera-hello
[0:02:01.541384500] [3922]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0+3156-f4070274
ERROR: *** no cameras available ***
```

To confirm if the camera is connected correctly I used:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=1
```

What I'm doing wrong? There is another way to test if the camera it's working?

Comment: Did you install the "64-bit" option?  From the [Release notes for the 2021-10-30 release:](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_armhf/release_notes.txt) `* Legacy camera subsystem removed from 64-bit RPi OS (still available on 32-bit)`.

Comment: [See also](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/4697)

Answer (score 1):

First, disable the legacy camera in raspi-config, and then add the following to your
`/boot/config.txt`
file:

```
dtoverlay=ov5647
```

and then reboot your Raspberry Pi OS and it should recognise your camera

Answer (score -1):

try using the command raspistill -o test.jpg

Comment: Not supported on Bullseye. Try command:  libcamera-still